# Why can't I install packages in Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, package, anaconda

I installed Anaconda from this [link](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe) and when I try to install other packages from Anaconda Navigator, I get the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package _tflow_select conflicts for:
keras -> tensorflow -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow-eigen -> _tflow_select==2.2.0=eigen
tensorflow-hub -> tensorflow[version='>=1.7.0'] -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow-metadata -> tensorflow -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.9.0 -> _tflow_select[version='==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|eigen']
keras-gpu -> tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.9.0 -> _tflow_select[version='==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|eigen']
tensorflow-probability -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14.0'] -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow-datasets -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14'] -> _tflow_select[version='==2.1.0|==2.2.0|==2.3.0',build='mkl|gpu|eigen']
tensorflow-mkl -> _tflow_select==2.3.0=mkl
tensorflow-gpu -> _tflow_select==2.1.0=gpu
keras-gpu -> tensorflow-gpu -> _tflow_select==2.1.0=gpu
Package tensorflow-base conflicts for:
tensorflow-mkl -> tensorflow==1.14.0 -> tensorflow-base[version='==1.10.0|==1.11.0|==1.12.0|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.14.0|==1.14.0',build='mkl_py36ha978198_0|mkl_py36hcaf7020_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|mkl_py35h81393da_0|mkl_py37hcaf7020_0|mkl_py37ha978198_0']
keras -> tensorflow -> tensorflow-base[version='==1.10.0|==1.11.0|==1.11.0|==1.11.0|==1.12.0|==1.12.0|==1.12.0|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0',build='gpu_py35h6e53903_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py37h55fc52a_0|gpu_py36h55fc52a_0|gpu_py37h871c8ca_0|gpu_py36h871c8ca_0|gpu_py36h0fff12a_0|eigen_py37hf8af7b3_0|eigen_py36hf8af7b3_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|eigen_py35h45df0d8_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py35h6e53903_0|mkl_py35h81393da_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|gpu_py37h0fff12a_0|mkl_py36hcaf7020_0|mkl_py37hcaf7020_0|eigen_py36hdbc3f0e_0|eigen_py37hdbc3f0e_0|gpu_py36h9ee611f_0|gpu_py37h9ee611f_0|mkl_py36ha978198_0|mkl_py37ha978198_0|eigen_py35h45df0d8_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0']
tensorflow-estimator -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base[version='==1.10.0|==1.11.0|==1.11.0|==1.11.0|==1.12.0|==1.12.0|==1.12.0|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.13.1|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.14.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0|==1.9.0',build='gpu_py35h6e53903_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py37h55fc52a_0|gpu_py36h55fc52a_0|gpu_py37h871c8ca_0|gpu_py36h871c8ca_0|gpu_py36h0fff12a_0|eigen_py37hf8af7b3_0|eigen_py36hf8af7b3_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|eigen_py35h45df0d8_0|eigen_py36h45df0d8_0|gpu_py35h6e53903_0|mkl_py35h81393da_0|mkl_py36h81393da_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0|gpu_py37h0fff12a_0|mkl_py36hcaf7020_0|mkl_py37hcaf7020_0|eigen_py36hdbc3f0e_0|eigen_py37hdbc3f0e_0|gpu_py36h9ee611f_0|gpu_py37h9ee611f_0|mkl_py36ha978198_0|mkl_py37ha978198_0|eigen_py35h45df0d8_0|gpu_py36h6e53903_0']
keras-gpu -> tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.9.0 -> tensorflow-base==1.14.0=gpu_py37h9ee611f_0 -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow-eigen -> tensorflow==1.9.0 -> tensorflow-base==1.13.1=eigen_py37hf8af7b3_0 -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow-datasets -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14'] -> tensorflow-estimator[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0'] -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow-mkl -> tensorflow==1.14.0 -> tensorflow-base==1.14.0=mkl_py37ha978198_0 -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-estimator[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0'] -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
tensorflow-base
...
```

I mention that I have only the root environment. Does anybody know what these conflicts mean and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install into a new environment instead of the conda root environment.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: This error most of the times happens when you don't install new packages in New venv. Make sure you creat new one and Activated. Then try to install packages you need.